# I can't print JSON notification in PHP, but I can save it in a file

Tags: php, json

I am receiving JSON notification about new order on my page. I can save the notification in a log file but I can't print it in PHP.

Here is the PHP Code that I use now:

```
    global $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;
    ini_set("allow_url_include", "On");
    if (!isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) {
        $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = file_get_contents('php://input');
    }
    echo "<hr>";
    echo 'Trying to var dump or to print_r $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA';
    var_dump($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);    
    print_r($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
    echo "<hr>";
    echo 'trying with file_get_contents("php://input")';
    $mydata = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $mydata = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($mydata);
    echo "</pre>";
    echo "<hr>";
    echo 'Trying with $_POST:';
    var_dump($_POST);
    echo "<hr>";
    echo 'Trying with $_GET:';
    var_dump($_GET);
    echo "<hr>";
    var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")));
    echo "<hr>";
    // PLEASE READ THIS:
    // All the above code prints nothing, NULL or empty Array
    // Howevver, the code bellow do save the notification in a log file.

    $now = date('Y-m-d-His');
    function mwrite($text,$time) {
    $filename = "/var/sites/m/mmmm.mmm/public_html/myflder/myfile_".$time.".log";
        $handle = fopen($filename, "w");
        fwrite($handle, $text);
        fclose($handle);
    }
        if (!isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) {
            $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = file_get_contents('php://input');
        }
        mwrite($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, $now);
```

Here is the notification that I save in a file:

```
{
    "e5Notification": {
    "orderNotification": {
      "purchase": {
        "purchaseId": "00002",
        "purchaseDate": "2017-07-28T04:05:44",
        "purchaseOrigin": "online",
        "paymentCompleteDate": "2017-07-28T04:05:44",
        "paymentStatus": "test payment arrived",
        "customerData": {
          "billingContact": {
            "lastName": "dfasdfas",
            "firstName": "dfasfa",
            "email": "ffdsfadf@sdfsd.com",
            "address": {
              "street1": "n/a",
              "postalCode": "n/a",
              "countryId": "ZZ",
              "country": "SomeCountry"
            }
          },
          "deliveryContact": {
            "lastName": "dfasdfas",
            "firstName": "dfasfa",
            "email": "ffdsfadf@sdfsd.com",
            "address": {
              "street1": "n/a",
              "postalCode": "n/a",
              "countryId": "ZZ",
              "country": "SomeCountry"
            }
          },
          "customerPaymentData": {
            "paymentMethod": "Other",
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "language": "English",
          "subscribeNewsletter": "false"
        },
        "purchaseItem": {
          "runningNo": "1",
          "productId": "0001",
          "productName": "My Product",
          "notificationNo": "0",
          "deliveryType": "Electronically",
          "currency": "USD",
          "quantity": "1",
          "productSinglePrice": "44.99",
          "vatPct": "18.00",
          "discount": "0.00",
          "extendedDownloadPrice": "0.00",
          "manualOrderPrice": "0.00",
          "shippingPrice": "0.00",
          "shippingVatPct": "0.00",
          "subscription": {
            "startDate": "2017-07-28T00:00:00",
            "interval": "Half Yearly without end"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I can not understand is why I can save the notification in a file, but I can't print it out with PHP. 
Also, can anyone tell me why I get 2 files printed, one empty one and second with this data? I am calling the function only once?

Comment: I am receiving the notification from a site that clear credit card. Person come to my site,create an order and is redirected to the payment site. They send the notification to a page that  I have specified.

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd party service you are using is calling back to your script with the JSON notification in the body. When that happens your script runs. If you print the results at that point, using `echo`, `print_r` etc, you are essentially printing it back to the client that called the page - i.e. the 3rd party. You would not expect to be able to display it to the browser using that mechanism. You need to use some other mechanism to match the data to the client session in the browser.

You might be getting two files because you get 1 when the 3rd party calls back into your server with the notification, and a second when you try to "view" the result by opening the same file in your browser, but you are not sending any body in the request, hence the log file is empty.

Such third-party processes often provide a callback (such as you are receiving) and also a mechanism so that you can provide a redirect url that they will send back to the browser, so that your user can return to your apps flow in the proper context after the transaction completes.

What service are you using?

Comment: It is share-it, or else known as digitalriver. I am looking at their manual, but I can't find out how to handle the notification. Any idea?

Comment: If you are using their payment page product, you would need to look at the "Return URL" parameter you are sending to createPaymentPageURl API you use to redirect to their payment page.

Comment: I will test that right now, even that I have been told that Return URL is for continue shopping page, but I will test it now

Comment: Grab the data from the query string returned to your return URL which you can use to populate your db, or to display the results to the user, like a thank you page. I believe the return url returns the data in an encoded query string which you will need to unpack.

Comment: I will test now, but until now, the $_GET was empty, as you can see from my  php code above

Comment: Is that the script you are redirecting to in return url?

Comment: Yes, that is the script.

Comment: I just did the test, and adding the "Return URL" change nothing. I have specified that elsewhere, they guided me so I am now getting the notification, the problem is I can't print it in my PHP, so I can enter the data that I need in my database. I can save the notification in a file, but I can't print it in PHP, and I don't know why.

Comment: You cant print it because you are not the caller (nor is your client) when you receive the notification. If all you need to do is process it, then do so when the data is available (it is when you write the file) and don't worry about printing it. Print it in your scripts after retrieving from the db. But I've integrated several payment pathways and there is usually a way to do this in the return URL.

Comment: What happens to your customer after the payment completes? They have to be redirected somewhere? Or are you only receiving notification (using their cart or similar). In that case, as above, printing is irrelevant - you are not  the client when the script is called

Comment: Why I am not the caller? User is redirected back on my site, and the script above is the scrip that is invoked. So I should be able to print the data in the php. Or I think so. So, user has been redirected back to my stie, and  I not only have to process the data then and there, but I will have to log in the user, to redirect him, etc, etc. I am looking at their manual again and again, but I can't find any solution so far.

Comment: Can you share a link to the documentation? It would be unusual for a redirect to include a body data in this fashion.

Comment: Sure, give me a moment

Comment: This is as I thought - this is the notification api - which covers server-to-server communication, not the browser to server path you are looking for. Typical for payment processors, they provide both a mechanism to get transaction info in the user context (usually by a redirect) and a separate mechanism for asynchronous notification to your server (which is what this documentation describes). Is there documentation that you use to direct to the payment page? That is where you'll find the answer. I'm happy to look at it as well.

Comment: That is all that I get from the documentation.I can ask them if they have anythying else. I won't get any answer until monday however. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: You must have something that tells you how to get the user to the payment page? Thats not in these docs

Comment: Let me check again trough my e-mails

Comment: What is the reference you used to create the code that redirects the user to the share-it payment page?

Comment: They have button, generate link that I use to create the link to their page. From there on, I used the documentation that I post you. They did help me to set up the cart page via e-mail but that is it.

Comment: Can we use the chat for faster exchange of the messages?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150472/discussion-between-richgoldmd-and-user2417624).

Comment: I checked the flow of data and its clear that this third party does not return any data in the redirect. (Is there an option to set when creating the link?) In such cases, a workflow you can use id to respond with a thank you screen and indicate they will receive an email. On the server, respond to the notification and update your db, etc, send the verification email thereafter and include a link back to your site or instructions to log in etc.

Comment: I sent them an e-mail and I will see what they will reply. Thanks for your help however

Comment: You're welcome. I'd be happy to hear follow-up when you have some clarity.